# Accessing URLs of iCloud files

Tags: php, objective-c, macos, icloud

I'm very confused as to how Apple intends iCloud to work with web apps; they stated that there will be web application support, but there seems to be no API to access iCloud files from anything other than a Mac or iOS application.

What I am trying to do is access a .md iA Writer file from a php based application. I have searched and searched but there seems to be no easy way of accessing the files a given app uploads.

Is there something really obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no web API (yet). If your PHP script could access files written by other applications without the developer's file type docs, then you're bound to create incompatible changes. (I understand that Markdown is an open format, but I'm speaking more generically.) Applications being able to view and edit other applications' data could lead to UX issues or possibly security issues.

Comment: Not sure if I was clear, but I only want to **read** the markdown files, not write them.

Comment: I still don't know about any public API to let you do that.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. Yeah I know there is no API to do it, and there seems to be no known hacks to get around it either at this stage unfortunately.